# VN7 792G Black Edition with windows 7

Tags: windows-7, audio, drivers, acer-aspire

I have managed to install windows 7 on VN7 792G Black Edition.

The last thing what's left is sound.

Realtek ALC255 sound card is not recognized, but It is detected on PCI bus.

I have been trying to manually add this driver (with success), but error code 10 was displayed.

Anyone knows about 3rd party drivers, which could probably works with this notebook?

I need windows 7 for my work, but I like this notebook look's, so I would like to keep it (I have still couple days to return it and get something else).

Comment: According to the Research done on this [Forum](http://community.acer.com/t5/Legacy-Laptops-and-Netbooks/Aspire-VN7-792G-Windows-7-Driver/td-p/401746/page/3) the SST audio drivers are not supported on windows 7. Which is why its not working properly.

Comment: If you really wanted to keep it you could run windows 7 in a Virtual machine on the laptop. Unless the company needs only windows 7 to be on there. Such as for Enterprise settings.

Comment: Yes, I have found this forum earlier, but I thought someone might know an answer on this site :/